# how to create Dataset after importing txt file

Tags: data-structures

I would like to translate a imported txt file to Dataset.

```
test = Import["E:\\mathematica\\example.txt", "table", 
       {"FieldSeparators" -> ",", "CharacterEncoding" -> "ASCII"}]
```

The result is:

> {{"naam A", "naam B", "naam C", "naam D"}, {1, 2, 1.2, "a"}, {2, 3, 
>     2.3, "b"}, {3, 4, 2.3, "c"}, {4, 5, 4.5, "d"}, {5, 6, 5.6, "e"}, {6,
>      7, 6.7, "f"}, {7, 8, 7.8, "g"}, {8, 9, 8.9, "h"}, {9, 10, 9.1, 
>     "i"}, {10, 11, 10.1, "j"}}

Now I would like to translate it to `Dataset` which is new in *Methematica 10.0*.

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"naam A" -> 1, "naam B" -> "2", "naam C" -> {1.1}, "naam D" -> {a}|>,
   <|"naam A" -> 2, "naam B" -> "3", "naam C" -> {1.2}, "naam D" -> {b}|>,
   <|"naam A" -> 3, "naam B" -> "4", "naam C" -> {1.3}, "naam D" -> {c}|>,
   ....
   }]
```

I tried it with the next code:

```
data = Dataset[<|"key1" -> test[[All, 1]], "key2" -> test[[All, 2]], 
   "key3" -> test[[All, 3]], "key4" -> test[[All, 4]]|>]
```

This code gives the wrong output. Anyone a suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Where did {1.1} come from? 1.1 does not exist in the Imported data. And is {} necessary? Anyway, you can code like "Module[{header = First@test},
  Inner[Rule, header, #, Association] & /@ (Rest@test)
  ] // Dataset".

Comment: you could just use SemanticImport which generates a Dataset for you

Comment: What error are you getting? "Unknown box name ``TypeSystem`TypeMap``"?

Comment: @gogoolplex, SemanticImport  doesn't guarantee anything and in 10.0.0 is not ready for prime time.

Answer (score 7):

[gogoolplex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1407/gogoolplex)'s suggestion to use `SemanticImport` is probably the easiest solution to your particular problem, but here is a way to assemble a dataset yourself.

```
table = {{"naam A", "naam B", "naam C", "naam D"}, {1, 2, 1.2, 
"a"}, {2, 3, 2.3, "b"}, {3, 4, 2.3, "c"}, {4, 5, 4.5, "d"}, {5, 6,
 5.6, "e"}, {6, 7, 6.7, "f"}, {7, 8, 7.8, "g"}, {8, 9, 8.9, 
"h"}, {9, 10, 9.1, "i"}, {10, 11, 10.1, "j"}};

With[{header = First@table}, 
  AssociationThread[header -> #] & /@ Rest@table] // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing one of the values with missing data, eg the empty String "" and see if SemanticImport still works.

Comment: This is also a useful approach if you already have an array of data (i.e. from a database query in SQLExecute) and would like to turn it into a Dataset without reading and writing files.